# Is there a way to catch consumer cancelled events in aio-pika?

Tags: rabbitmq, python-asyncio

The title says it all. I see that I can catch the channel close event but I get no error at all if I remotely delete the queue being consumed from. I'm using aio-pika 6.6.0 and Python 3.7.7.